# D3.js bar chart colors not shown in print out but displayed on browser

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have written a script to display bar chart using d3.js
The chart is being displayed on the browser , but when I try to print the page , in print preview I only see the text on the chart and no colors and bars.

Can anyone please help me fix this . 
I want to persist the bars and colors in the print outs also.
Printing it normally using Ctrl-P

Comment: how do you print the bar chart...can you put that part of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On doing CTRL+P you have to check the option **Background colors and images** in the print page options.

This option is available on Chrome and FF  for IE I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS I added this,

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

And it worked.
But this works only in Chrome 26+ and Safari 6+.

http://maxlapides.com/forcing-browsers-print-backgrounds/